# How to use variable outside of try-catch block

Tags: java, variables, encryption, try-catch

I am making a decryption program and I'm not quite sure how to use the variable "cip" out side of my try catch block. I tried moving the 3 lines of where is asks user to input pattern but i ran into other problems.

my code is:

```
     import java.util.*;

public class unscrambler //This class will encrpyt the program
{
 public static void main (String [] args){
   int cip= 0;
   String user ="";




   System.out.println("Please enter the code to unscramble"); 
   Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //imports scanner reader
    String userinput = inputScanner.next();
    char[] charArray = userinput.toCharArray(); //sends userinput to charArray
    int j=charArray.length;

    Character [] array = new Character[j];

    for(int w=0; w<j; w++){
      array[w] = charArray[w];
    }

    int a=1;
               System.out.println("Please enter the number cipher pattern (an integer)");
    do{
      try{

         user = inputScanner.next();
        cip = Integer.parseInt(user);
        a=2;
        System.out.println("your code is ");

 for(int w =0; w<j;){
   System.out.println(charArray[j]);

   w+=cip;
 }
          if(cip<=0){
          System.out.println("please enter number greater than zero");
a=1;
}
}catch(NumberFormatException f){
  System.out.println("please enter a proper number");
}
}while(a==1);


 }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you should learn about booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You're only making the declarations in that block.

```
String user = inputScanner.next();
int cip = Integer.parseInt(user);
```

Add these to the start of the file, just after the `main()` line:

```
int cip = 0;
String user = "";
```

The errors after just moving (without the `=` stuff) indicate that you're using `cip` after the `try` block, so we need to initialise it with empty data in case the `try` fails.

Now just change the lines that you've currently got in the `try` block to:

```
// Remove the 'String' part.
user = inputScanner.next();
// Remove the 'int' part.
cip = Integer.parseInt(user);
```

And then you can move on to the next unrelated bug.

Comment: I moved the lines out of the try catch but when i run the program it goes to error after it asks the pattern and the word

Comment: You need to change the lines to remove the types at the start, and declare the variables at the start of the program on different lines as `String user;` and `int cip;`. Moving them will probably give you problems.

Comment: I have done this but it remins the same issue. I just getting long lines or error after it asks my the pattern and word

Comment: Updated with a working solution for this problem (that I've tested).

Comment: could you post the change you made maybe i was doing something different than u

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to either move the variable declaration outside of the loop, or move the place you want to use it inside the loop.

Java doesn't allow you to use a local variable outside of the scope in which it was declared.  Period.

> I tried moving the 3 lines of where is asks user to input pattern but i ran into other problems.

Well ... you need to solve those other problems!

Programming is like this.  You need to work within the constraints of the programming language that you are using.

---

I can see what is causing your latest error, but I'm not going to tell you what it is.  Instead, I'm going to tell you how to find it for yourself.

The "line upon line of output" is a Java Stacktrace.  It contains A LOT of useful information, and you need to learn how to interpret it.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 
at unscrambler.main(unscrambler.java:35) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
```

Stacktraces typically report an exception that has been thrown somewhere in your running program.

**Step 0:** Find the stacktrace.

The first line gives the name of the exception, and the message.  In this case, the name of the exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` and the message is (just) "5".

**Step 1:** If you don't recognize the name of the exception, *look it up* in the javadocs.

Here it is: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).  Read it now.

**Step 2:** Try to understand the message.  In this case, you just need to know that the message is the *value* of the index that was out of range.  But you should be able to guess that ... based on the javadoc for the exception.  (Usually the messages are a bit more informative, but this one is being thrown from compiled code, and for technical reasons a more informative error would be difficult to produce.)

The second line of the stacktrace tells you where the exception was thrown.  In this case, line 35 of "unscrambler.java" ... in the `main` method.

**Step 3:** Open the source file in an editor or your IDE, and see what the code at that line says.

In this case it is (I think) this line:

```
    System.out.println(charArray[j]);
```

**Step 4:** Now you have to start thinking.  (Thinking is a very important part debugging!)  How can that line have possibly thrown that exception?  What could have caused that?

In this case, the first think to observe is that there is only one place on that line where you are doing array indexing, and it is the expression `charArray[j]`.  So that means that ... (*you fill in the details*).  But were did ... (*you fill in the details*) come from?  Take a look at what happened before this statement.  See it yet?  (*If no, then look again.*  It should be really obvious if you look carefully!)

The rest is for you to sort out ... :-)

Comment: OK, so what do you want me to do about that?  Hint: how about *telling us* what your problem is?

Comment: my error is i am able to get the program to successfully as about the pattern and the word to unscramble. but right after the program outputs "your code is" then i get lines upons lines of errors

Comment: And what do those "lines upon lines of errors" say?  (Sheesh!  Getting information out of you is about as painful as pulling out teeth!!)

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at unscrambler.main(unscrambler.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)